# Using subscript in paste command

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear))+
geom_bar() + 
     labs(x="", 
     y="",
     title="A plot",
     subtitle=expression('v'[total]* '= X'))
```

I would like to replace `X` with something like `sum(mtcars$mpg)`. With `paste` I could use `paste("v_total =",  sum(mtcars$mpg))`. How can I change the `_` to a subscript like that in expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `bquote` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear))+
  geom_bar() + 
  labs(x="", 
       y="",
       title="A plot",
       subtitle=bquote(~v[total] == ~ .(sum(mtcars$mpg))))
```

[image]